# How to remove between first parentheses? (preg_replace)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need help, I have one regular expression but I don't understand.

I have this:

```
$string = '(54) (11) 4444 5555';
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

Output: `4444 5555`

But I need this output: `(11) 4444 5555`

And if I have (54(1(1))9) (11(2(3))) 4444 5555 
I need (11(2(3))) 4444 5555.

Without first parentheses.

Thx.

Comment: You don't need regexes for this. just strpos() to find the first `)` and a substr() operation to extract the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '(54) (11) 4444 5555';
echo  preg_replace("/^\([0-9]+\) /", "", $string);
```

Output

```
(11) 4444 5555
```

Comment: Tanks is work for '(54) (11) 4444 5555' and if I have '(54(1(1))9) (11(2(3))) 4444 5555' I need '(11(2(3))) 4444 5555'.

Comment: Then use `/^\([0-9\(\)]+\) /` in the [] sections is the allowed chars, until a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx instead: `^((\(.*?)(\)\s))(.*)$`

```
$string = '(54(1(1))9) (11(2(3))) 4444 5555';
echo  preg_replace("/^((\(.*?)(\)\s))(.*)$/", "", $string);

Input: (54(1(1))9) (11(2(3))) 4444 5555
Output: (11(2(3))) 4444 5555
```

An example of the working RegEx is on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pS9fZ5/1). The page also offers an explanation of what each section of the RegEx matches.